# Area of triangle on a sphere (not spherical triangle)

Tags: triangles, 3d, area, spherical-geometry

How do I find the area of a triangle on a sphere, and the triangle is not a spherical triangle, for example, the triangle is formed with two geodesics and a line of latitude.

Is there a specific name for this kind of triangle?

Answer (score 1):

You should compute surface integral I suppose. In such case I'd change variables to those corresponding to three planes that cutting your 'triangle' out of sphere.